# How to create color swatch for Product in Product List

Tags: shopify, liquid

On my main page I have a block with a product catalog and I need to display radio buttons with colors and sizes. I'm bringing out product-variant-picker snippet from Dawn. I need to style the color buttons to match this color. For this purpose I created a metafield. The problem is that I display the label of the radio button, but due to the fact that one size has one color, the same color is displayed twice, but when you add to the cart, everything is added correctly. The problem is in the metafield output.

For example, a product has 4 colors and two sizes. That is, he has 8 options. And when I display the code below, I have 4 color buttons as it should be, but the first two are the same color and the second two are a different color. This is due to the fact that there are two variants of the same color.

```js
//product-variant-picker

{%- unless product.has_only_default_variant -%}
  <variant-radios
    id="variant-radios-{{ section.id }}"
    class="no-js-hidden"
    data-section="{{ section.id }}"
    data-url="{{ product.url }}"
    {% if update_url == false %}
      data-update-url="false"
    {% endif %}
  >
    {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
      <fieldset class="js product-form__input">
        {% render 'custom-product-variant-options', product: product, option: option %}
      </fieldset>
    {%- endfor -%}
    <script type="application/json">
      {{ product.variants | json }}
    </script>
  </variant-radios>
{%- endunless -%}

//product-variant-options

{%- liquid
  assign variants_available_arr = product.variants | map: 'available'
  assign variants_option1_arr = product.variants | map: 'option1'
  assign variants_option2_arr = product.variants | map: 'option2'
  assign variants_option3_arr = product.variants | map: 'option3'

  assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id
-%}

{%- for value in option.values -%}
  {%- liquid
    assign option_disabled = true

    for option1_name in variants_option1_arr
      case option.position
        when 1
          if variants_option1_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
        when 2
          if option1_name == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 and variants_option2_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
        when 3
          if option1_name == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 and variants_option2_arr[forloop.index0] == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option2 and variants_option3_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
      endcase
    endfor
  -%}

  <input
    type="radio"
    id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
    name="{{ option.name }}"
    value="{{ value | escape }}"
    form="{{ product_form_id }}"
    {% if option.selected_value == value %}
      checked
    {% endif %}
    {% if option_disabled %}
      class="disabled"
    {% endif %}
  >

  {% if option.name == 'Color' %}
    <label
      class="color-swatch"
      style="background-color: {{ product.variants[forloop.index0].metafields.custom.color }}"
      for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
    >
    </label>
  {% else %}
    <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
      {{ value }}
    </label>
  {% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```

```js
  <ul
        class="products-with-filter__content-products  grid product-grid grid--3-col-desktop"
        data-id="{{ section.id }}"
      >
 {%- paginate collections.all.products by section.settings.products_per_page -%}
          {% for product in collections.all.products %}

<li>
...
 {% render 'product-variant-picker', product: product, product_form_id: product_form_id %}
      {%- render 'buy-buttons',
        product: product,
        product_form_id: product_form_id,
        section_id: section.id,
        show_pickup_availability: true
      -%}
</li>
          {% endfor %}
        {%- endpaginate -%}
</ul>
```

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xisq9.png)

[What comes out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld3q8.png)

Comment: Hey, can you add the piece of code where you are rendering this file? For dawn its usually `product-variant-picker.liquid`.

Comment: @NattoShaw Hi. Added part of the code

Comment: Hey @Marling, I was referring for the code of `product-variant-picker.liquid` not where it is referenced. This code you added is helpful but not enough to view the whole picture. In Dawn there are 3 files in play with regards to display variants. `product-variant-options.liquid`, `product-variant-picker.liquid` and the file where the latter is referenced. From my understanding you only provided the first and last file but not the second. Correct me if I'm wrong or maybe you have a different setup

Comment: @NattoShaw Yes, you are right, I misunderstood. I provided the code for my files product-variant-options.liquid and product-variant-picker.liquid. They are slightly modified in that I removed the select from them and left only radio buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tthis issue is happening because you need to get the variant correctly inside `product-variant-options.liquid`. The `forloop.index0` represents the variant options not the variant itself. This causes you to refer an incorrect variant.

Try the following code, this would get the correct variant by looping through the variant options.

```html
{%- liquid
  assign variants_available_arr = product.variants | map: 'available'
  assign variants_option1_arr = product.variants | map: 'option1'
  assign variants_option2_arr = product.variants | map: 'option2'
  assign variants_option3_arr = product.variants | map: 'option3'

  assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id
-%}

{%- for value in option.values -%}
  {%- liquid
    assign option_disabled = true

    for option1_name in variants_option1_arr
      case option.position
        when 1
          if variants_option1_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
        when 2
          if option1_name == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 and variants_option2_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
        when 3
          if option1_name == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 and variants_option2_arr[forloop.index0] == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option2 and variants_option3_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
      endcase
    endfor
  -%}

  {% liquid
    assign variant_needed = null 
    for variant in product.variants 
      if variant.options contains value 
        assign variant_needed = variant 
      endif 
    endfor 
  %}

  <input
    type="radio"
    id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
    name="{{ option.name }}"
    value="{{ value | escape }}"
    form="{{ product_form_id }}"
    {% if option.selected_value == value %}
      checked
    {% endif %}
    {% if option_disabled %}
      class="disabled"
    {% endif %}
  >

  {% if option.name == 'Color' %}
    <label
      class="color-swatch"
      style="background-color: {{ variant_needed.metafields.custom.color }}"
      for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
    >
    </label>
  {% else %}
    <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
      {{ value }}
    </label>
  {% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
```